# Create an External Table in Spark without moving data files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have a few external files and I want to create tables out of it without moving those files. Those are in ORC.

This is what I'm doing:

```
val df = spark.read.option("inferSchema",true).orc("abc_file_path")
df.show() -- this works fine and shows the schema and record

df.write.option("path", "abc_file_path").saveAsTable("xyz.abc")
```

The write action throws error about file doesn't exist in the abc_file_path. It looks like the file is getting deleted as well during this operation. It also throws this warning:

*It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is expected behaviour as you are reading data from `abc_file_path` & writing to same path without any write modes.

Even if you specify write mode it will overwrite existing files or data in that location & tested in spark 3.5.0 version.

here is git code - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.5/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala